# How to modify the input coordinate of a runtime shader in?

Tags: android

In the documents:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RuntimeShader

AGSL

It discribed as below
"Additionally, if the shader is invoked by another using setInputShader(java.lang.String, android.graphics.Shader), then that parent shader may modify the input coordinates arbitrarily."

But there is no example how to modify it in the parent shader.

In other words, I want to use normalized coordinates similar to GLSL to sample an input Bitmap so that I can directly access the entire content of the bitmap without needing to know its original resolution, but currently, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

I try to pass the bitmap origin width use Uniform iWidth， and the canvas iResolution to caculate it.

`image.eval(fragCoord/iResolution.x*iWidth).rgba`

But this approach lacks any flexibility.

Comment: Did you consider using `setInputBuffer` instead of `setInputShader`, and let the parent shader paint into the buffer, and do the coordinate transformations on the buffer?